# Multiplying numbers in a list (coordinate-wise) without using mapcar in Lisp

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, vector-multiplication

I'm having trouble with the output of my code, I think it's when I'm checking conditions for the null of my lists.

The question I am trying to complete is: Write a function `vecmul` that will take as inputs two simple lists of numbers. vecmul should multiply these lists coordinate-wise as one would multiply vectors. Assume the two lists are the same length. [For example, `(vecmul '(2 3 4 5) '(1 4 5 2))` returns `(2*1 3*4 4*5 5*2)` or `(2 12 20 10)`. You are not allowed to use `mapcar` for this function]

So far I have

```
(defun vecmul (list list2)
  (cond ((null list) 0)
     (t (cons (* (car list) (car list2))
                 (vecmul (cdr list) (cdr list2))))))

[170]> (setq l '(2 4 6))
(2 4 6)
[171]> (setq r '(1 3 5))
(1 3 5)
[172]> (vecmul l r)
(2 12 30 . 0)
```

I'm getting the correct numbers, it's just that the list is adding the "." and the "0" at the end of the list. I'm pretty sure it's because i'm not stopping the recursion right or not working the cond right. I'm just not entirely sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it almost right. However, you're terminating your list with `0`, when the correct termination is `nil`. This code works:

```
(defun vecmul (list list2)
  (cond ((null list) nil)
     (t (cons (* (car list) (car list2)) (vecmul (cdr list) (cdr list2))))))
```

When you call `(cons 1 2)`, the cons cell you get is written `(1 . 2)`. the notation `(1 2 3 4 5)` is just shorthand for `(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . nil)))))`. If the `cdr` of the last cons cell is `6`, not `nil`, then you get `(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . 6)))))`, which shortens to `(1 2 3 4 5 . 6)`.

Answer (score 4):

Neil Forrester answered your question.

Some more remarks. Use modern names in Lisp: `first` and `rest`.

```
(defun vecmul (list1 list2)
  (cond ((null list1) nil)
        (t (cons (* (first list1) (first list2))
                 (vecmul (rest list1) (rest list2))))))
```

If you have a simple true and false decision, `IF` might be better. Since list operations are involved, I would write it as the following and not use `WHEN`.

```
(defun vecmul (list1 list2)
  (if (null list1)
      nil
    (cons (* (first list1) (first list2))
          (vecmul (rest list1) (rest list2)))))
```

Best use a loop construct or mapping in **real code**. Recursion, as above, has a stack depth limit. A loop does not have that restriction.

```
(defun vecmul (list1 list2)
  (loop for e1 in list1 and e2 in list2
        collect (* e1 e2)))
```

or

```
(defun vecmul (list1 list2)
  (mapcar #'* list1 list2))
```